# Microsoft Edge contenteditable bug with selection in nodes with height or overflow

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, microsoft-edge

It seems that Edge will not allow a selection on multiple divs when they are in contenteditable and the divs have either their height or overflow set (other styles may also cause this).

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyLv1aq0/) you will see that Chrome and Firefox allow the selection but Edge does not.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  <div class="content1">start selection somewhere on this line</div>
  <div class="content1">and end on this line somewhere</div>
</div>
```

where

```
.content1 {
  height:   40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

How can this be avoided/fixed?